# Why is my for loop not iterating in this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, turing-machines

```
eachconfig = [['a', ['blank', ['p1', 'r', 'r'], ['b']]], ['b', ['blank', ['p0'], ['c']]], ['c', ['blank', ['r', 'r'], ['a']]]]
def turingmachine(data):
    a = 0
    tape = []
    finalmc = data[0][0]
    for z in range(1,40):
        tape.append(' ')
    mcName = []
    m = 0
    for emc in range(1,len(data)+1):
        goal = data[m][0]
        mcName.append(goal)
        m+=1
    mcNumber = [h-1 for h in range(1,len(mcName)+1)]
    mcNameNumber = dict(zip(mcName,mcNumber))

    d = 0
    tapeposition = d
    tapescan = tape[d]
    for process in range(1,len(tape)):
        b = 0
        c = 0

        cconfig = data[a][b]
        if cconfig == finalmc:
            b += 1
            scannedsymbol = data[a][b][c]
            if isinstance(scannedsymbol, str):
                if scannedsymbol.lower() in ('any', 'blank'):
                    c += 1
                    operations = data[a][b][c]
                    for cycle in operations:
                        if cycle[0] in ('p','P'):
                            tape[tapeposition] = cycle[1:]
                        elif cycle[0] in ('r', 'R'):
                            tapeposition += 1
                        elif cycle[0] in ('l', 'L'):
                            tapeposition -= 1
                        elif cycle[0] in ('e', 'E'):
                            tape[tapeposition] == ' '   
                    finalmc = data[a][b][-1][0]
                    a = mcNameNumber[finalmc]
        return tape



print turingmachine(eachconfig)
```

My efficiency may not be amazing in this code, nor is it complete, it's merely a framework for the set data in the current 'eachconfig' list. With that said, though, the output of the program is still just `[1, ' ', ' ', ' ', ...]`, where it should be `[1, ' ' , 0 , ' ' , 1 , ' ' , 0 , ...]`

I've read over the code dozens of times, I've bug checked by printing out each line as it goes, and I've discovered the problem being that it only iterates through the loop once(the loop in question  is the `for process in range(1,len(data)+1):` loop, the loops before that one are merely for initializing), but I can't figure out why. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it len(tape) or len(data)?

Comment: mcNameNumber = {num: name for num, name in enumerate(mcName)}

Comment: Why do you use multi-level lists and not multi-level dictionary?

Comment: Aside: `tape[tapeposition] == ' '` should probably be `=` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `tape` in inner cycle, the one with `process in range(...)`, so only one iteration happens. Your `tape` also is not long enough, you make several operations per each `tape` available space, I also didn't find any "termination" symbol, so it never will be long enough with such `for` conditions.

Here is "fixed" code:

```
eachconfig = [['a', ['blank', ['p1', 'r', 'r'], ['b']]], ['b', ['blank', ['p0'], ['c']]], ['c', ['blank', ['r', 'r'], ['a']]]]
def turingmachine(data):
    a = 0
    tape = []
    finalmc = data[0][0]
    for z in range(1,40):
        tape.append(' ')
    mcName = []
    m = 0
    for emc in range(1,len(data)+1):
        goal = data[m][0]
        mcName.append(goal)
        m+=1
    mcNumber = [h-1 for h in range(1,len(mcName)+1)]
    mcNameNumber = dict(zip(mcName,mcNumber))

    d = 0
    tapeposition = d
    tapescan = tape[d]
    for process in range(1,len(tape) - 8):
        b = 0
        c = 0

        cconfig = data[a][b]
        if cconfig == finalmc:
            b += 1
            scannedsymbol = data[a][b][c]
            if isinstance(scannedsymbol, str):
                if scannedsymbol.lower() in ('any', 'blank'):
                    c += 1
                    operations = data[a][b][c]
                    for cycle in operations:
                        if cycle[0] in ('p','P'):
                            tape[tapeposition] = cycle[1:]
                        elif cycle[0] in ('r', 'R'):
                            tapeposition += 1
                        elif cycle[0] in ('l', 'L'):
                            tapeposition -= 1
                        elif cycle[0] in ('e', 'E'):
                            tape[tapeposition] == ' '
                    finalmc = data[a][b][-1][0]
                    a = mcNameNumber[finalmc]
    return tape

print turingmachine(eachconfig)
```

Comment: Where did you get the -8 for len(tape)?

Comment: Empirically, by trial and error. But it almost checks out, each 3 iterations you increase `tapeposition` by 4, 2 for `a` and 2 for `c`. To get to position 40 you need `x = 40 / 4 * 3 = 30` iterations, given the fact that you've got a mess in your index and length handling (e.g. your tape length is actually 39, not 40, and `process` loop is also shorter by 1), 8 looks about right `39 * (1 - 3 / 4) - 1 = 8.75`.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8712069e1ccef9a1d1e2) is the code to better understand how it goes. The last unaccounted `0.75` iteration goes into `tapeposition` increment, which is why no `IndexError` happens.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: because your return statement is inside the for loop. So, probably just an indentation error.

But this code is, I must say, pretty un-Pythonic. You're doing lots of iterating through ranges, which should always be a red flag: in Python you usually want to iterate through an actual thing, not a specially-constructed range. In any case, since you're not even using the loop variable (`process`), you should consider if a for loop is the right structure at all.

Plus, as volcano points out in the comments, most of your setup code can be shortened significantly.